# REGEX - control

Tags: regex

I've got the following example text:

```
There are 7 apples, 3 lemons.
```

I've got a software, which search with regex pattern, but two times: one for "apples" (as attribute) and a second time for "7" (as value).

My problem is: if i search with the pattern "lemons", it will find "lemons" and if i search with "\d", it will find "7", but i want "3".

My question is: How can i control the regex engine?

Comment: `((\d+) (\w+))` and then get the group values from each match. https://regex101.com/r/jL6pI9/1

Answer (score 0):

If you want the digit associated with `lemons` use this pattern:

```
/(\d+)\slemons/
```

If you want the digit associated with `apples` use this pattern:

```
/(\d+)\sapples/
```

Obviously this could be DRYed up by a program that allows you to enter the `lemons` or `apples` portion. It could take the entered pattern and prepend the `(\d+)\s` regex to the literal text for which you're searching. I'll leave that part up to you.

If you want to extract all occurrences of words with digits near them, you can use this regex to parse your unstructured data...

```
/(\d+)\s(\w+)/g
```

...to get something like:

```
\1 # 7
\2 # apples

\1 # 3
\2 # lemons
```

Comment: First question: What are the "/" symbols? Second question: The problem is, I only can write regex pattern, without accessing program code. Which regex pattern can access the second group of a match?

Comment: 1. You can omit the `/` symbols. They're just a convention to denote a regular expression. 2. `\1` will access the first group of a match; `\2` will access the second group of a match.

Comment: Okay, i understand. But I need a regex pattern which find "3 lemons" and returns simultaneously(!) the "3". Because i can only one regex and have no further access to the results (groups)...

Comment: Then use `(\d+)\s(lemons)` and access the `3` by using `\1`... What program are you using? `sed`? `awk`? Would help a lot to include these things in your question. It's material information when you are asking for a bunch of follow-up implementation questions.